# How can I persist data for a redirect with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm attempting to validate a users login attempt and inform them that

- Their username is wrong or
- their password is wrong (because I personally hate with a blind fury when a website doesn't inform me WHICH it is but that's beside the point).

I've read a lot of SO posts on this issue but the ones I've found are years old and I'm dealing with CodeIgniter [3.0.1](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

This is the code that I have in place. I'm using `Eclipse PDT` to as my IDE and I like it quite a bit (but that's getting off track) so I've been able to step through the execution and watch as it just fails completely.

```
IF (!$this->User->login( //Testing shows this works fine - the SWITCH statement gets executed as it should and the BADUSERNAME case is followed through.
    addslashes(strtolower($this->input->post('username', TRUE))),
    addslashes($this->input->post('password', TRUE)),
    $this->getIP())){
        SWITCH($this->User->ID){
            CASE 'BADUSERNAME':
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_msg', 'Invalid Username');
                BREAK;
            CASE 'BADPASSWORD':
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_msg', 'Invalid Password');
                BREAK;
            CASE 'ALREADYLOGGEDIN':
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_msg', 'You are logged in elsewhere.');
                BREAK;
            DEFAULT:
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_msg', 'Something has gone terribly wrong. Please try logging in again.');
                BREAK;
            }
            redirect(base_url());
        }
```

Then a bit further down I load the header, body, and footer views - The body is where the error message should be displayed but ***it's not.***.

```
<div id="contentarea">
    <div class="container">
        <?PHP
        ECHO $this->session->flashdata('show_validation') ? validation_errors() : ''; 
        $error = $this->session->flashdata('user_msg'); //This is where it's supposed to get it...
        IF ($error) //And this is where it's supposed to show it...
            ECHO "<div class='error'>$error</div>";
        ?> //But the value is wiped so it only ever grabs NULL.
```

I've followed the path of execution after calling the redirect after setting the flash data and I've noticed that after the redirect finishes it's chain of execution, it calls `exit;`.

Then everything loads again from the `index.php` file, and when Session finally pops up... the value '`user_msg`' is nowhere to be found.

So clearly I'm doing something wrong here - what am I doing wrong here? Will the flash_data only persist until that redirect is called? Even the session_data values (calling `$this->session->value = 'some arbitrary user message'` fails to persist).

How can I persist the message for the next time the body element is loaded so that it can tell the user "Hey, didn't find you" or "Hey, your password wasn't right"?

### EDIT 1

So it turns out I do not need to redirect for what I am doing as POSTing (submitting the user name and password) handles that for me.

I'm going to leave the question here for anyone else who may need it answered though - perhaps the answer is simply that Flash data just doesn't survive a redirect?

Comment: [I can not see the methods you use in CI 3.0 docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)

Comment: @ODelibalta "the methods you use" - to which are you referring?

Comment: I think you should consider that there is a reason that many websites don't tell you which out of username and/or password is incorrect.  It is a security concern.  If you tell an attacker that they have a good username but just a bad password, then you have given them 50% of what they need to successfully attack you.

Answer (score 1):

Flashed data is only available for the next http request, if you reload the page a second time, data is gone. 
To persist data in the session, you want to set the variable in the session.

[Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#how-do-sessions-work)

> Adding Session Data
>   Let’s say a particular user logs into your site. Once authenticated, you could add their username and e-mail address to the session, making that data globally available to you without having to run a database query when you need it.
>   You can simply assign data to the `$_SESSION` array, as with any other variable. Or as a property of `$this->session`.
>   Alternatively, the old method of assigning it as “userdata” is also available. That however passing an array containing your new data to the set_userdata() method:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
$this->session->set_userdata('username', 'username is wrong');
```

in the view

```
$this -> session ->userdata('username');
```

or

```
$this ->session -> username;
```

Reference Session Library [Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).
hope this help.

Comment: I did say in my question that I had tried to do as you suggested but that did not work either ($this->session->foo = 'bar' does not persist either).

Comment: @Will you are read Codeigniter session documentation and how to use it. `$this -> session -> foo = bar` does not set the variable in the session.  but this does and its the correct syntax  `$this -> session ->set_useradata('key','value')`. again read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use `$this->session->keep_flashdata('user_msg')` with `$this->session->unset_userdata('user_msg')`

here is the solution (view file)

```
<?php
$error = $this->session->flashdata('user_msg');
if (isset($error)) {
    echo '<div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
     $this->session->unset_userdata('user_msg');
}

?>
```

After that in your controller `construct` function (In that controller where you redirecting)

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  //.....
  $this->session->keep_flashdata('user_msg');
}
```

I had same problem and this works. do not forget to clear cache when try or try in different browser

Comment: Thank you for the tip - however, on the initial run with the constructor gone, attempting to call keep_flashdata results in an exception. I'm sure I can work that out though. This seems to be more along the correct track.

Comment: post your full `exception` message here

Comment: It was my mistake - I was calling the wrong function. I was able to find the solution, but this wasn't it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter's flashdata to display errors separately.

This is what I usually use.

Controller:

```
$errors = array();
foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value){
    $errors[$key] = form_error($key);
};
$response['errors'] = array_filter($errors);
$this->session->set_flashdata($response['errors']);
redirect('your-page', 'refresh');
```

And the to display the errors use

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('field_name'); ?>
```